# Issues With Pusher-js client in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I am using `vue 3` to build a realtime chat app. I am also using `laravel-echo@^1.10.0` and `pusher-js@^7.0.3`.

**In the `main.js`**
I instantiated the laravel-echo and passed in the credential from the .env file

```
const app = createApp(App)

app.config.globalProperties.$appUrl = window.location.origin
app.config.globalProperties.$serverUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + "api";
let token = localStorage.getItem("apiToken");
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  Accept: 'application/json',
};

import Pusher from "pusher-js";
Pusher;
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Echo = new Echo({
  authHost: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
  authEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + "api/company/broadcasting/auth",
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  key: process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_KEY,
  cluster: process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_CLUSTER,
  // encrypted: true,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    },
  },
});


app.component('Spinner', Spinner)
app.component('Pagination', Pagination)
app.component(VueCountdown.name, VueCountdown)

app.use(VueToast, { position: 'top-right' })
app.use(plugin, defaultConfig)
app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.use(VueAxios, axios)
app.mount('#app')
```

**In the chat UI**
I now subscribed to the channel and listen to the event

```
onMounted(async() => {
      await getChat();
      if(errorOnChatLoading.value){
        router.push({ name: 'NoChat' });
        toast.error(traverseError(errorOnChatLoading.value));
      }
      
       window.Echo.private(`message.received`).listen("WhatsappIncomingMessageEvent", function(e) {
         console.log(2);
       })
      
    })
```

**This issue I am facing is that when the component mounts, the channel is successfully subscribed to and it even starts listening to events. When you trigger events it is logged to the network tab.**

[image]

The event comes through and is logged to the network tab but that same event is not passed into the event handler so I can use it to affect the UI.

Basically,

```
window.Echo.private(`message.received`).listen("WhatsappIncomingMessageEvent", function(e) {
 console.log(2);
})
```

The `console.log(2)` above is not fired.

***PS***
I have tried the latest versions, I have tried prefixing the event name with a `.`, I have even tried using the pusher-js itself without the laravel-echo. I have tried using created() and mounted() in the options-api.

```
// instantiate and configure pusher
      let token = localStorage.getItem("apiToken");
      const pusher = new Pusher(process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_KEY, {
        cluster: process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_CLUSTER,
        authEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + "api/company/broadcasting/auth",
        auth: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          },
        },
      });
      // subscribe and bind in mounted hook
      let channel = pusher.subscribe(`private-message.received`);
      channel.bind('.WhatsappIncomingMessageEvent', function(data) {
        console.log(2);
      })
```

***No resolution***

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full event name, which according to the screenshot is `App\\Events\\WhatsappIncomingMessageEvent`. This should then allow you to pass the event to the handler.

Comment: ```window.Echo.private(`message.received`).listen("App\\Events\\WhatsappIncomingMessageEvent", function(e) {
    console.log(2);
   })

```
This still didnt work

Comment: If I might add, it not even about passing the event to the handler, the handler is not been fired in the first place.